# Typescript React component won't export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

There are a few related questions, but none of them are helping...

I want to export some React components from a typescript library (that I intend to publish on npm).

I'm using npm link to test it locally before publishing.

The library structure looks like this:

src/components/index.ts:

```
export { default as SomeComponent } from './SomeComponent';
```

src/components/SomeComponent.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import '../styles.css';

const SomeComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return <div className="ts-component">test</div>;
};

export default SomeComponent
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "rootDir": "./src/components",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "declaration": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "baseUrl": "./src",
    },
    "include": ["./src"]
  }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ts-lib-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "dsfsdf",
  "main": "src/components/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/components/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'ts-lib-test',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

src/styles.css:

```
.ts-component {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1rem;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I'm building the library with `npx webpack` and then linking with `npm link`, then the consuming project looks like:

```
import './App.css'
import { SomeComponent } from 'ts-lib-test'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {'This is where the test component goes:'}
      <SomeComponent />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is the most simplified version I could make, and I can't get this to work. When I start the project I get

`export 'SomeComponent' (imported as 'SomeComponent') was not found in 'ts-lib-test' (module has no exports)`

Am I making this harder for myself than it should be? I showed this to ChatGPT and it said it should be working, which is also true according to every relevant SO post I can find...
Should I not be doing this with typescript? Should I just create-react-library instead? I'd like to define prop types for my components if possible.
I'm tearing my hair out over this...

Comment: Looks like `main` in `package.json` being set to `src/components/index.ts` is part of the problem. Shouldn't this be the JS file in `dist`?

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting and importing it wrong.

1. When you use the default export just use

```
  import SomeComponent from 'ts-lib-test';
```

2. When you want to use the named exports you need to export it in this way

```
 export {SomeComponent};
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still couldn't find any exports from the module. I think it might have something to do with the relative import for the styles... I'm experimenting with that now. I had a simpler version working earlier without any styles, and I'm trying to get it back to that state